# Comparison ASP.NET and ASP.NET 4.6

Tags: asp.net-core

Just wondering how is it with performance is asp.net core in comparison with ASP.NET 4.6. Did someone performance tests?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/benchmarks It only measures pure http performance/overhead and requests per second for delivering out a plaintext result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In generaly **ASP.NET Core has much better performance than current ASP.NET 4.x versions**. Architecture has changed and ASP.NET Core is no longer based on System.Web.dll (This in itself has a positive effect on performance). Great article about ASP.NET Core performance is [on ageofascento.com](http://www.ageofascent.com/asp-net-core-exeeds-1-15-million-requests-12-6-gbps/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know between 4.6 and Core but here's the [ASP.NET Benchmarks repository](https://github.com/aspnet/benchmarks).

They load test the framework and see at which point it fails. I think what you are looking for is inside one of the Excel spreadsheet in the repository.